# Map QVariant type to SQLite type

Tags: sql, dictionary, qvariant

I need to convert type of QVariant variable to QString of SQLite data type.
It seems, that QSqlDriver should do that, but I can't find any method for such conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just created method with switch-case structure to return QString value for each QVariant::Type...